# Insert/update object array with meteor-autoform

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, meteor-autoform

I have

```
Schema.User = new SimpleSchema({
  fullName: {
    type: String,
  },
  contracts: {
    type: [Object],
  },
  "contracts.$.start_date": {
    type: Date,
  },
  "contracts.$.end_date": {
    type: Date,
  },
  "contracts.$.salary": {
    type: Number,
  }
});

Meteor.users.attachSchema(Schema.User);
```

Not I want to display the form in my template, making it possible to update name and add/remove/update contracts.

I have tried

```
{{> quickForm collection="Meteor.users" id="updateUserContractsForm" type="update" doc=this fields="fullName,contracts"}}
```

but I can only update fullName. If I am trying to add new contracts, they wont get saved. I guess it's because I have `type="update"` instead of `type="insert"`, so it wont allow me to insert edit the contracts since they don't exist yet.

Am I right? Can I do something to mix insert/update?

Comment: I may be wrong but creating a Schema for Meteor.users should be a lot more involved than the code you currently have: https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-collection2/blob/master/README.md#attach-a-schema-to-meteorusers

Comment: And FYI `type="update"` allows you to update an existing document in your DB collection. `type="insert"` will create an entirely new document in your DB collection. You are trying to add new contracts to an existing user, right? You should be using `update`.

Comment: I am using `update` but the contracts wont be saved. My user schema looks like the one from your link, besides from the added contracts fields. I just wanted to make it look simple :-)

Comment: Do I have to allow insert/update or something? I cannot understand why they aren't saved